# Monkeyrunner: How do you access elements using their relative position instead of absolute co-ordinates?

Tags: android, python, automation, monkeyrunner

I want to `automate` testing of an android app, and `monkeyrunner` is a tool I am considering using as it works with `python` (I haven't learned java).

I have automated desktop webpage testing using `Selenium WebDriver` before and that allowed me to access elements via their html attributes or relative `Xpath`, but looking at the monkeyrunner api, it seems you can only use absolute x,y coordinates, which is not useful due to the varying sizes of android devices.

Is there a way other than absolute positioning to access elements using monkeyrunner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [AndroidViewclient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient). It locates Views based on their attributes like id, text, content description, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use uiautomator. It's a tool from Google used to test the UI. You can use it to test apps from a fake user perspective. You can simulate clicks, drags, long presses on elements identified by their id or a combination of properties.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html

The tests can be written in Java. However, there is a Python wrapper for this and it works great. Have a look at:

https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator

It has most of the original tool's features and the scripts are easier to write.